# Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined VUEX

Tags: javascript, undefined, vuex, commit

Please help me it always says Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined. Here is my code in store.js.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
     timer: null,
     totaltime: (25 * 60)
  }, 
  mutations:{
    startTimer: (state, context) => {
    //here is the problem part I think
      state.timer = setInterval(() => context.commit('countDown'),
      1000)
    },
    countDown: state => {
      var time = state.totaltime
      if(time >= 1){
        time--
      }else{
        time = 0
      }
    },
    stopTimer: state => {
      clearInterval(state.timer)
      state.timer = null
    },
    resetTimer: state => {
      state.totaltime = (25 * 60)
      clearInterval(state.timer)
    }
  },
  getters:{
      minutes: state => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(state.totaltime / 60);
        return minutes;
      },
      seconds: (state, getters) => {
        const seconds = state.totaltime - (getters.minutes * 60);
        return seconds;
      }
  },
  actions:{


  }
})
```

I have problem it debugging. it always says like this
'Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined'

Here is my Timer.vue code for calling

```
methods: {
      formTime(time){
        return (time < 10 ? '0' : '') + time;
      },
      startTimer(){
        this.resetButton = true
        this.$store.commit('startTimer')
      },
      stopTimer(){
        this.$store.commit('stopTimer')
      },
      resetTimer(){
        this.$store.commit('resetTimer')
      },

    },
    computed: {
      minutes(){
        var minutes = this.$store.getters.minutes;
        return this.formTime(minutes)
      },
      seconds(){
        var seconds = this.$store.getters.seconds;
        return this.formTime(seconds);
      },
      timer: {
        get(){
          return this.$store.state.timer
        }
      }
    }
```

My code in Timer.vue script computed and methods. I cannot track where the problem is... Please help me Im stuck with this here.

Comment: May I see as to how you call the `startTimer(state, context)`?

Comment: `startTimer(){
        this.resetButton = true
        this.$store.commit('startTimer')
      },`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutations do not have access to any `context`. They are meant to be atomic, that is they work directly with one facet of state. You should make your `startTimer` an *action* that commits the `timer` and then starts the countdown

```js
mutations: {
  // add this one for setting the timer
  setTimer (state, timer) {
    state.timer = timer
  }
},
actions: {
  startTimer ({ commit }) {
    commit('stopTimer') // just a guess but you might need this
    commit('setTimer', setInterval(() => {
      commit('countDown')
    }, 1000))
  }
}
```

This would need to be called via `dispatch` instead of `commit`

```js
this.$store.dispatch('startTimer')
```