# Vuex uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined in .vue and .js file

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my first time learning to use vuex and I'm building a simple authorization with hardcoded value. I want to redirect user to **Products.vue** if the entered password in **Confirm.vue** matches.

Products.vue will contain the secured content that the user cannot access before entering the correct password.

The result keeps on giving error of
uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined` in my Confirm.vue file

**Confirm.vue**

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <p>Please enter password</p>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          v-model="input.password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button type="button" v-on:click="login()">Go to admin</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "Confirm",
      data() {
        return {
          input: {
            password: "",
          },
        };
      },
      methods: {
        login() {
          if (this.input.password == "123") {
            this.$store.commit("setAuthentication, true");
            this.$router.replace({ name: "products" });
          } else {
            console.log("incorect password");
          }
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

So my assumption is that `$store` is not defined, but I already set the constant for it in my Main.js and also created a new Vue.

**Main.js**

```js
    import Vue from "vue";
    import Vuex from "vuex";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import VueRouter from "vue-router";
    import Confirm from "./pages/admin/Confirm.vue";
    import Products from "./pages/admin/Products.vue";
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    Vue.use(Vuex);
    
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        authenticated: false,
      },
      mutations: {
        setAuthentication(state, status) {
          state.authenticated = status;
        },
      },
    });
    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes: [
        {
          path: "/",
          redirect: {
            name: "main",
          },
        },
        {
          path: "/admin/confirm",
          name: "confirm",
          component: Confirm,
        },
        {
          path: "/admin/products",
          name: "products",
          component: Products,
        },
      ],
    });
    
    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(App),
      router: router,
      store: store,
    }).$mount("#app");
```

Lastly, this is the content of App.vue

**App.vue**

```html
    <template>
      <router-view />
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "app",
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59315728/cannot-read-property-commit-of-undefined-vuex

Comment: The code you've posted should work without error. There must be other `commit` references that aren't shown in the question. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the mutation wrong.

You are using this syntax -

```
this.$store.commit("setAuthentication, true");
```

Instead, you should use this

```
this.$store.commit("setAuthentication", true);
```

Comment: thank you, but it is still showing the same error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined`

Comment: Try using mapMutations from the vuex

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components

Comment: Use the above link to see the docs how can you use map mutaions